# Correct way to set color to transparent with matplotlib.pcolormesh()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like values under a certain level (in this case `0`) to be plotted as transparent with `matplotlib.pcolormesh()`, and I cannot seem to get anything working with the options that I have found.

I have tried setting the `kwarg` `vmin=1`, and I have tried setting the limit with `plt.cm.cmap.set_under(alpha=0)`.

**Update**: After playing around with a sample script, it appears that `vmin` is working correctly for me there, so it appears to be do to some other confounding factor. I am using `Basemap` and attempting to plot a density map, setting the levels based on the min/max values of the data (with everything else being zero).

**My sample script showing vmin working**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,4,num=4)
y = np.linspace(1,6,num=6)
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)

ydim, xdim = x_mesh.shape

z = np.zeros(((ydim-1),(xdim-1)))

for j in range(ydim-1):
    for i in range(xdim-1):
        z[j,i] = (random.random())+4.

z[1:4,1:2]=0

cmap = plt.cm.Reds
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap=cmap, vmin=4)

plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a masked array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.sin(np.arange(100) / 2).reshape(10, 10)
z = np.ma.masked_array(z, z < -.5)

cmap = plt.cm.Reds
plt.pcolormesh(z, vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap="RdYlBu")
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes yes yes! Still not sure what my problem was with `vmin`, but that did the trick. Interesting, as I tried a similar approch using `np.ma.masked_where()`, and that didn't work. Thanks a ton! AND your plot is much more politely sized than mine :) I'll fix that.