# How do I make a heatmap in Cartopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scientific-computing, cartopy

I am mapping latitude, longitude, and then a separate value on cartopy.

How do I make the points colored like a heatmap based the list called klist? I cant find any snippets of code where it will work with cartopy

That list has range of values that I want colored based on the how big the value is.

```
# Define a Cartopy 'ordinary' lat-lon coordinate reference system.
crs_latlon = ccrs.PlateCarree()


def make_plot(projection_name, projection_crs):

    ax = plt.axes(projection=projection_crs)

# Set display limits to include a set region of latitude * longitude.
# (Note: Cartopy-specific).
    ax.set_extent((-65.0, -62, 44, 45.5), crs=crs_latlon)

# Add coastlines and meridians/parallels (Cartopy-specific).
    ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.2, color='black')
    ax.gridlines(crs=crs_latlon, linestyle='-')



# Mark some particular places with a small circle and a name label...
# Define some test points with latitude and longitude coordinates.
    #city_data = [('Halifax, NS', 44.67, -63.61)]

    plt.plot(lon,lat,marker='x', markersize=1.0, markeredgewidth=2.5,
             markerfacecolor='black',
             transform=crs_latlon)
# Add a title, and display.
    iplt.show("Mission #1: Attenuation Coeffiecient")

def main():
# Demonstrate with two different display projections.
    make_plot('Equidistant Cylindrical', ccrs.PlateCarree())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should make your code a MWE. As it stands, the modules are not `import`ed. Also, `klist` does not appear in your code. Is it really a list, a `np.array`... ? In any case, it would be nice a have a `klist` with random/garbage data for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, you would produce a heat map the same way you would produce a heat map in plain `matplotlib`. Just use `pcolormesh` (or `pcolor` or whatever) and with a properly defined meshgrid. Here, I modified @berna1111's answer to produce a color map instead of drawing circles on the map.

To avoid drawing outside the coastlines, you could use a [masked array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669704/correct-way-to-set-color-to-transparent-with-matplotlib-pcolormesh) or use [transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177718/use-a-variable-to-set-alpha-opacity-in-a-colormap), although the former would probably be best.

In the following example, I supply a `heat_data` that is a numpy array that contains the data that will be colour coded. I assume that this data is defined over the whole map range for convenience. Your data may differ.
Because I don't have the actual data, I create `lat` and `lon` arrays from the extent and the size of `heat_data`. In the `main()`, I generate some noise to fill `heat_data` and create the plot.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_plot(projection_name, projection_crs, extent, heat_data):
    """
    ?
    """
    fig = plt.figure()
    rect = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8
    ax = fig.add_axes(rect, projection=projection_crs)

    # Set display limits to include a set region of latitude * longitude.
    # (Note: Cartopy-specific).
    ax.set_extent(extent, crs=projection_crs)

    # Add coastlines and meridians/parallels (Cartopy-specific).
    ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.2, color='black')
    ax.gridlines(crs=projection_crs, linestyle='-')

    lat = np.linspace(extent[0],extent[1],heat_data.shape[0])
    lon = np.linspace(extent[2],extent[3],heat_data.shape[1])
    Lat,Lon = np.meshgrid(lat,lon)
    ax.pcolormesh(Lat,Lon,np.transpose(heat_data))
    plt.savefig("Test_fig.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')


def main():
    #extent = (-65.0, -62, 44, 45.5)
    extent = (-90, -40, 30, 60)
    # Define some test points with latitude and longitude coordinates.
    #city_data = [('Halifax, NS', 44.67, -63.61, 'black'),
    #             ('Neighbour', 45, -63, 'blue'),
    #             ('Other_Place', 44.1, -64, 'red')]
    heat_data = np.random.normal(0.0,0.2,size=(100,150))

    # Demonstrate with two different display projections.
    # Define a Cartopy 'ordinary' lat-lon coordinate reference system.
    crs_latlon = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    make_plot('Equidistant Cylindrical', crs_latlon, extent, heat_data)
    #crs_ae = ccrs.LambertCylindrical()
    #make_plot('Lambert Cylindrical', crs_ae, extent, heat_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Heat map with cartopy]

Answer (score 0):

If you want different coloured points this might help you (based on your code):

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def make_plot(projection_name, projection_crs, extent, city_data):
    """
    ?
    """
    fig = plt.figure()
    rect = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8
    ax = fig.add_axes(rect, projection=projection_crs)

    # Set display limits to include a set region of latitude * longitude.
    # (Note: Cartopy-specific).
    ax.set_extent(extent, crs=projection_crs)

    # Add coastlines and meridians/parallels (Cartopy-specific).
    ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.2, color='black')
    ax.gridlines(crs=projection_crs, linestyle='-')

    # Mark some particular places with a small circle and a name label...
    for city in city_data:
        ax.plot(city[2], city[1], marker='o',
                markersize=2.0, markeredgewidth=1.0,
                markeredgecolor=city[3], markerfacecolor=city[3],
                linestyle='None', label=city[0], transform=projection_crs)
    # Add a title, legend, and display.
    ax.set_title(''.join(("Mission #1: Attenuation Coeffiecient - ",
                          projection_name)))
    ax.legend()
    fig.show()


def main():
    #extent = (-65.0, -62, 44, 45.5)
    extent = (-90, -40, 30, 60)
    # Define some test points with latitude and longitude coordinates.
    city_data = [('Halifax, NS', 44.67, -63.61, 'black'),
                 ('Neighbour', 45, -63, 'blue'),
                 ('Other_Place', 44.1, -64, 'red')]

    # Demonstrate with two different display projections.
    # Define a Cartopy 'ordinary' lat-lon coordinate reference system.
    crs_latlon = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    make_plot('Equidistant Cylindrical', crs_latlon, extent, city_data)
    crs_ae = ccrs.LambertCylindrical()
    make_plot('Lambert Cylindrical', crs_ae, extent, city_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Equidistant Cylindrical]
[image: Lambert Cylindrical]

I don't know enough about cartography to understand why the points are in different places in the two projections, but maybe you know what that means and how to correct it.

Comment: hi thanks for your response, I was actually looking to make a heat map with a colour bar based on points on a map. So each lat and lon point has a attached value to it that determines its colour. Sorry if I was not clear enough with that.